# PHP oci_connect() TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier (ORA-12154)

Tags: php, oracle

I'm testing some PHP code on Ubuntu server and oracle database connection is checked by the "tnsping" command

```
Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.3.14)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL) (SID = ORCL)))
OK (10 msec)
```

But, oci_connect function in PHP shows an warning like as

> Warning: oci_connect(): ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified in /usr/local/ipm5/wui/manager/123.bih on line 6 2

of course, the OCI8 is enabled(checked via phpinfo) and some environment(`PATH`,`ORACLE_BASE`,`ORACLE_HOME`,`ORACLE_SID`,`TNS_ADMIN`,`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ) variables are set into `/etc/bash.bashrc`

do anyone recommend?? what the problem is.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

instead of ORCL, you may want to put the whole string in oci_connect

```
(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.3.14)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL) (SID = ORCL)))
```

PHP code:

```
oci_connect($username, $password, '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.3.14)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL) (SID = ORCL)))');
```

check phpinfo() output "Environment" part, if you don't have ORACLE_HOME, TNS_ADMIN, you need to make those available to your PHP running environment,
for apache compiled with php_module

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/oracle_home
export TNS_ADMIN=/path/to/tns_admin
apachectl start
```

for php-cgi or php-fpm

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/oracle_home
export TNS_ADMIN=/path/to/tns_admin
/script/to/start/fpm
```

Comment: I know your answering way and it work fine. but i want to connect oracle via tns name because the oracle have multiple listener. of course, your code also can express multi listener but that way may cause some management problem... thanks.

Comment: @user2990252 you need to check the "Environment" of phpinfo output, to format the code display, I have updated my answer, thanks.

Comment: thanks a lot! i have one more question. you know export command is volatile so i want to know which file stores ORACLE_HOME environment?

Comment: you can store ORACLE_HOME variable in whatever file you like, to make ORACLE_HOME available to PHP, you just need to source that file before starting php fpm or apache, since you have defined it in /etc/bash.bashrc, you can do it this way `. /etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks for your good answer. I have change the ORACLE_HOME path and I can see the new value in command line but even after restarting apache I see the olod value on phpinfo() output "Environment" part (yet). What is wrong with it? Is it cached? How to refresh that?

Comment: I have environment ORACLE_HOME and TNS_ADMIN in Apache, but works only with whole string in oci_connect. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when using a remote database that is unreachable, or requires a VPN connection to be accessed.