# Connect to Remote Oracle Database though PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm connecting a PHP website to a database build using Oracle Apex. I am trying to work from home using WAMP. I've installed the Oracle Client (11.0.3 I think) but I now get the error;

> Warning: oci_connect(): ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect
>   identifier specified in

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Please refer this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345605/php-oci-connect-tnscould-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier-ora-12154

Comment: Have used the method you linked, set the IP to the IP of the web page I open Oracle from but now I get this error: Warning: oci_connect(): ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed in

Comment: Please update your question accordingly, now that the first issue was resolved